# Cannot install framed.sty when I use knitr and RStudio to produce a pdf file on Windows

Tags: r, windows, latex, rstudio, knitr

I am trying to use RStudio and knitr to produce PDF files on Windows 10. There is no LaTex on my computer. When clicking "Compile PDF" button, I have this error message:

```
LaTex Error: File 'framed.sty' not found.
==>Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced.
```

I found a framed.sty file under H:\R\win-library\3.3\knitr\misc. It looks like RStudio cannot find the path. So, I try some methods. For example, install framed package. I downloaded framed package from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed?lang=en.

However, all the websites I found are talking about the solution on Mac or Linux, for example https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/39. How can I fix this problem on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you were using MiKTeX on Windows. You can use its package manager to install a missing package: https://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html